# Is there any endpoint for events in Fabric?

Tags: google-fabric

I'd like to send events to Fabric from serverside (for e.g. via REST API), but I can't find any relevant information in the web docs if it's available: https://docs.fabric.io/web/fabric/overview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric doesn't have a public API that you can interact with in this way.